# Why is it considered 'powerful' to pass a function as a parameter?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am reading through *A Concise Introduction to Programming in Python* by Mark J.Johnson and I stumbled upon a piece of code that uses darts to estimate the area under the graph. The code is working perfectly fine but I am getting confused as to why you would pass a function as a parameter if you could just call the function anyway.

```
from random import uniform
from math import exp

def area(function , a ,b ,m ,n = 1000 ):   #changed parameter for better understanding
    hits = 0
    total_area = m * (b-a)
    for i in range(n):
        x = uniform(a,b)
        y = uniform(0,m)
        if y <= function(x):
           hits += 1

    frac = hits / float(n)
    return frac * total_area

def f(x):
    return exp(-x**2)

def g(x):          #new function
    return exp(-x**2) + 2

def main():
    print area(f,0,2,1)
    print area(g,0,2,1)
main()
```

He states that passing a function as a parameter is 'powerful' but I can't see why?

Comment: Now define a different graph function.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Sorry for the bad typos. Didn't realize my import line was double. Does the edited version show my understanding correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to show that you now understand the issue by adding the `g()` function? Because right now that serves to confuse more than to enlighten and requires that we now update our answers a bit too. Your question, as it stood, was clear enough.

Comment: I know it seems like a pedantic thing to point out, but you are passing a reference to a function, not the function itself.

Comment: A good answer to why functions as "first class citizens" is a good thing is probably too long for this format. Also, it is not Python specific.

Comment: I'm trying to show that I understand the issue by just adding another `print` statement with a different function `g` being passed. This helps so that I don't have to change the whole `area` function right?

Comment: Perhaps because it allows the actual function to be any object that can be called, which might not be a function at all (it could be an instance of a class with a `__call__()` method for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` is but *one graph function*. It is not the only function that you could define to create a graph.

You can also define other functions:

```
def g(x):
    return 2 * x ** 2 + x + 5
```

and pass this into `area()` **without having to alter that function**. `area()` is generic enough to calculate the area of different graph functions, and all you need to do is pass in the graph function to have it calculate that area.

Had you hardcoded `f` instead of using a parameter, you could no longer do that.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.  Upvoted to correct a miscarriage of justice.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer should be obvious, especially in this case: You can write a generic function for something like calculus integration that works on any function you pass in.  You can modify the function you're integrating by supplying a new function.  Likewise for other operations like graphing.

Comment: Like beauty, what's obvious is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Beauty is subjective; this is an objective technical observation.

Comment: Obvious means easily seen (or noticed) and on technical matters and their implications, would depend heavily on many factors, such as the observer's experience, exposure, education, etc. So, no, I don't think whether it is so or not is as cut-and-dried as you apparently do.